# number of binary heaps from 1..n

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Given the integers from 1 to n, determine how many valid binary heaps can be constructed with these numbers.

```
Example: 1 2 3 4
```

valid min heaps are: `{1 2 3 4}`, `{1 3 2 4}`, `{1 2 4 3}`,

Thus the answer is 3

Comment: Interesting problem... Can you show us what you've tried so far? we would be more likely to find a solution if you shared your work.

Comment: not much.. I tried to make a connection with the number of binary trees, i.e., Catalan numbers but no success so far

Comment: if you just did a little search on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ ...

Comment: Search [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/) to find http://oeis.org/A056971

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hint:

A binary heap has a predefined number of nodes, and a well defined structure (Complete tree)

Think recursively about this problem.

"Chose" which of the non-root numbers go to the left subtree, and which to the right - and recursively invoke on the subtrees.

```
f(1) = 1 //no sons
f(2) = f(1) * 1 //one son and a root
//chose which element will go to the left sub-tree, and recursively invoke.
f(3) = Chose(2,1)* f(1) * f(1) * 1 
f(4) = Chose(3,2)*f(2) * f(1) * 1 //chose which 2 elements will go to the left sub tree
...
```

The question is tagged as homework, so I am leaving finding the exact numbers for the general case up to you.